# Making union of some raster coverages without the area between them

Tags: postgis, raster, union

I have a set of raster coverages. Some of them are really far from each other. When I use ST_Union function to union them, the function fill the area between them.
I explain it in a simple example:
I have a grid of polygons and select 2 of them (by their id) that are not neighbours.

[image]

Now, I have two different polygons in a table. Then, I used ST_AsRaster() to make two rasters out of the two polygons.
At the end I used ST_Union() to make a union of those rasters.

```
select * 
INTO test1
from grid
where id= 277765 or id = 277762;

select st_asraster(tile_border,100,100, '8BSI'::text, 0, -1) as rast
into test1_rast_1
from test1 ;

select ST_Union(rast)
into test1_rast_1_union
from test1_rast_1;
```

I want the area between to be no-value but the ST_union fills it with 0. The created raster is as follows:

[image]

My real data consists of the raster coverages that are really far from each other and I have many layers that I want to union them.
How can I use ST_Union in a way that it does not fill the area between the two geometries? because I think filling it for each iteration takes a long long time.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I just made 3 changes to the previous code:

- I changed the pixel type from '8BSI' to '8BUI'
- I changed the initial pixel values from 0 to 1
- I changed the no-data value from -1 to 0

As you see only 3 parameters of the ST_AsRaster() are changed.

Now, the code results in a raster as follows:

[image]

As you see the area between the two rasters is not part of the final coverage.
The code I used is:

```
select * 
INTO test1
from grid
where id= 277765 or id = 277762;

select st_asraster(tile_border, 100, 100, '8BUI'::text, 1, 0) as rast
into test1_rast_1
from test1 ;

select ST_Union(rast)
into test1_rast_1_union
from test1_rast_1;
```